# Какая разница в интеграции видео с Youtube на мобильном приложении и на сайте для десктопа?

Tags: node.js, видео, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения, nextjs

У меня проблем нет. Сайт у меня адаптивный. Отображается и воспроизводится и на десктопах, и на мобильниках/планшетах.

**Десктоп:**

[image: десктоп]

**Мобильная версия:**

[image: мобильная версия]

Как я сделал такое: регулярками превратил в html-код для встраивания видео, + пару медиазапросов.

Интересует, как такое (встраивание видео) реализовывается для мобильных приложений? Неужели для мобильных приложений тоже достаточно "регулярками переварить" адресную строку в html-код?

Comment: ВАЖНО: я не спрашиваю КАК конкретно это сделать. Я спрашиваю ЕСТЬ л РАЗНИЦА?

Comment: Возможно позже в комментариях я укажу причину появления такого вопроса.

Comment: Про какую мобильную платформу идет речь? Укажите тег android или ios.

Comment: Например, для Android есть [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player), вот тут есть [демо-приложение](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads). Интеграция Youtube-видео в Android-приложениях это не регулярки, не адресная строка, не html. Это програмное API на языке Java.

Comment: @Vadik , если бы я знал это - я бы не спрашивал

Comment: *«Возможно позже в комментариях я укажу причину появления такого вопроса.»* @Aliskin, интрига не раскрыта.

Comment: @Vadik , перед тем как задать вопрос я пару сек погуглил - увидел кучу каких-то непонеятных импортов, и еще много чего неясного... А таперь зачем и почемсу я спрашиваю (отвечу кртатко, сухо, но постараюсь шобы было более-менне понятно). В период запрета вкантакта, однокл, майла и яндекса в Украине, ВСЕ ураинцы начали создаваь укрсоц сети (ukrainians. esvoe.com, soul.ua вулык друзи, сосиды, укрфэйс и прочее...) - все эти недосоцсети уже в прошлом или в проедпохоронном состоянии. И вна Украине есть одна всем известая КРЫПТОсоцсеть sl8.online - с весны или с начала лета ее создателди обещают

Comment: @Vadik , обещают сделать чтобы видео с тыТруба воспроизводилось внутри сети. Но уже осень... - до сих пор у них сплошные баги ошгибки тмены релизов и прочий бред. У них походу отдельные версии сайта для мобильных устройст и вебверсия. А я еще перед  тем как содавать свой проэкт, хорошенько подумал что и как: нужно ли мне заморачиваться отдельно с андройдами и вебверс (и как поддерживать это всё) ИЛИ делать одну версию для всех и всего? Ага, пару слов про sl8 - там, кроме ненависти ко всему русскому, нет ничего. Мой прогноз: оно уже умерло (и крыптовалюта их не спасёт).

Comment: @Vadik ,  По поводу есвое и соула ... %:))) можете глянуть esvoe.com soul.ua . О своем проэкте - я промолчу :)

Comment: @Vadik, какая жаль. чеерз минусы к моему вопросу, я уже не могу задавать новые вопросы. от трагедия %:)), но я это как-то переживу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для интеграции Youtube-видео в мобильное Android-приложение можно воспользоваться официальным [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player).

Там же можно скачать [демо-проект](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads) и посмотреть, как интегрировать Youtube-видео в Android-проект.

При написании приложений на мобильных платформах используют соответствующее программное API. Для Android это API обычно может быть написано на Java или Kotiln, а для iOS это языки Objective-C или Swift. И никакого HTML.

Разница с веб-приложениями существенная.

Comment: Успел к окончанию конкурса. Поздрал, вы получили награду. А минус к моему вопросу я не знаю кто почему и зачем ставят.